# No route is shown using MKDirectionsRequest & MKMapView, xcode prints 'unexpected waypoint index'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkmapview, swift3

I am trying to get route between two locations.

Following is my code for class function:

```
func fetchRoute(index: Int){
    self.resultView.isHidden = true;
    destLocation = self.arrResult[index];

    let request: MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = curLocation
    request.destination = destLocation
    request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile;
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

    directions.calculate { [unowned self] response, error in
        guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }
        for route in unwrappedResponse.routes {
            self.mapView.add(route.polyline)
            self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

And for delegate Method:

```
extension MapView : MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: overlay as! MKPolyline)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        return renderer
    }

}
```

When run, it give following messages in console:

```
_errorCodeForProblemDetail: unexpected waypoint index
nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x4
nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received WRITE_CLOSE event
tcp_connection_cancel 1
nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1 gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com:443 ready resolver (satisfied)]
nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.1 17.130.137.75:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)]
nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.2 17.130.137.77:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
__nw_socket_service_writes_block_invoke sendmsg(fd 9, 37 bytes): socket has been closed
cancelled socket-flow (null)] Socket protocol sent error: [32] Broken pipe
nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [1.2 17.130.137.77:443 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected
nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.3 17.130.137.73:443 initial path (null)]
nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.4 17.130.137.79:443 initial path (null)]
nw_resolver_cancel_on_queue 0x7d9fa730
[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc] 1
```

But there is no output on map view! Nothing happens!

I am using Swift 3.0 & Xcode 8.0

Comment: OS log will print in Xcode 8. The above working or not ?. If you want to remove is logs use OS_ACTIVITY_MODE in target

Comment: @Vinodh no logs are not problem, the issue is only logs are printed no result on map view, I've edited my question to mention this point.

Comment: @demonofthemist did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Cognoscis No, after further research I found out that apple map do not provide this service in India. So I switched to google maps! Will delete this question now as it is not relevant.

Comment: @demonofthemist Yes, I too just found that out. I would suggest you add the above as your answer and accept it. It might be helpful to someone like me who is new to iOS

Comment: @Cognoscis Yes I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this answer just to guide any future users facing this issue.

After further research on above topic I found out that Direction API of Apple Maps is not supported in my country, i.e. India. That was the reason I was getting this message. Thus I switched to Google Maps, which provide a good support in India.